# jquery dialog load form via ajax, submit form back to modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dialog, modal-dialog

I combined a couple stackoverflow questions to get the code below. The links load the edit form in a modal fine via ajax, but when the form is submitted the whole page submits and reloads. I would like only the modal to reload.

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".ajax").click( showDialog );

//variable to reference window
$myWindow = jQuery('##myDiv');

//instantiate the dialog
$myWindow.dialog({ height: 350,
width: 400,
modal: true,
position: 'center',
autoOpen:false,
title:'Edit Policy',
overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'},
open: function(type,data) { $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); }
});
}
);

//function to show dialog   
var showDialog = function() {
$('##myDiv').load(
this.href,
{},
function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
//if the contents have been hidden with css, you need this
$myWindow.show(); 
//open the dialog
$myWindow.dialog("open");
}
);

//prevent the browser to follow the link
return false;
}

//function to close dialog, probably called by a button in the dialog
var closeDialog = function() {
$myWindow.dialog("close");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

- submit the form via AJAX
- submit the form to a hidden Iframe

After the submit, handle updating the model contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting a form via the jQuery `load` method like this:

```
$("#myDiv").load("your_submit_page_url_here", $("#yourFormIdHere").serializeArray());
```

The `serializeArray` method will convert your form contents into the JSON format that `load` method accepts. The whole call will basically load the content of page that results after submit into the `myDiv`. `yourFormIdHere` is the id that you gave your `<form>` tag